# Keyboard light on after computer shutting self down

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

I've been having problems getting my desktop to boot as of late. There are a few possibilities as to why this is, but it turned on yesterday while I was in class and I decided to leave it on.  Today when I got back from the academic side of campus my computer was off but one of the keyboard lights was stuck on. I could not turn the computer back on again and this computer has never done that before.  The motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-P43-ES3G with 6 Gigs of RAM a GTX 460 and a Q6600 processor. I was wondering if the keyboard light being on was a signifier of something being wrong. I do have a support ticket into Gigabyte, but they can take a while to respond (especially since its the weekend). Any help suggestions are welcome, thank you.

P.S. - I've been having problems with this computer since the summer. I've replaced the motherboard and graphics card (unrelated problem) and have tried using an alternate power switch, RAM configuration (only 4 gigs, only 2 gigs etc) and have placed electrical tape on the motherboard plate to cover up some scratches there. I'm leaning towards this being a power supply issue, but it passes the paperclip in the green wire and a black wire test.